# Getting a select option instead of different buttons php class

Tags: php, html

Im trying to get a select between the different sizes of the product. I made a script which echos a button for every size but how can i do this with a select form?

In the DB the product has a master and every size is an option.

To get the product im using `($_GET['add'])` to get the product on the cart page.
At the last past im giving the `wagen.html?add='.$s['id']` so i can use that id in the cart.

```
class ProductDisplay {

    public function display($content){
        global $db, $properties, $cms, $adb;
        $content = unserialize($content);

        $itm = $adb->queryrow("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=? LIMIT 1", array(intval($content['wlpid'])));
        $vat = $adb->querykeyvalues("SELECT id, multiplier FROM tax");
        $prijs = (($itm['price']*($vat[$itm['tax']]/100))/100);

        $subs = $adb->queryarray("SELECT *, (SELECT value FROM propertyvarchar WHERE lang=1 AND propid=1 AND product=p.id lIMIT 1) as name, (SELECT value FROM propertyvarchar WHERE lang=1 AND propid=5 AND product=p.id lIMIT 1) as opt FROM products p WHERE master=?", array($itm['id']));

        echo '
        <div id="the_product_container" class="para_container"></div>
        <div id="anchor_1_product"></div>
        <div id="anchor_2_product"></div>
        <div id="anchor_3_product"></div>
        <div id="page_product" class="anchor_pos"></div>
        <div id="page_product_check" class="anchor_check"></div>

        <div class="bonds">
            <div class="scaleme">
                <img alt="shirt" class="content" src="/uploaded/overige/'.$content['main'].'">';
                $ar = array(
                    1=>"point_one",
                    2=>"point_two",
                    3=>"point_tree",
                    4=>"point_four",
                    5=>"point_five",
                );
                for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
                {
                    if(!empty($content['info'.$i]))
                        echo '<img alt="Product point" id="'.$ar[$i].'" class="'.$ar[$i].'" src="/uploaded/overige/'.$content['info'.$i].'">';
                }

            echo '</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mobiel_text_con">';
            for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
            {
                if(!empty($content['info'.$i]))
                    echo '<div class="text_block">
                        <h3>'.$content['info'.$i.'h'].'</h3>
                        <hr />
                        <p>
                            '.$content['info'.$i.'t'].'
                        </p>
                    </div>';
            }
        echo '</div>';

        if(empty($subs))
        {
            echo '<div class="pricetag">
              <p>'.number_format($prijs,2,',','.').' &euro;</p>
            </div>
            <div class="button_holder_ordernow">
                <a title="Order Now" href="/winkelwagen.html?add='.$itm['id'].'" class="sumbit_button">order now</a>
            </div>
            <div class="photo_overlay_filter2"></div>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<div style="display:inline-block; text-align:center; width:100%;">
                <div class="pricetag">
                  <p>'.$itm['name'].' ('.$itm['opt'].') '.number_format($prijs,2,',','.').' &euro;</p>
                </div>
                <div style="display:inline-block;">
                    <div class="button_holder_ordernow" style=" padding-bottom:20px;">
                        <a title="Order Now" href="/winkelwagen.html?add='.$itm['id'].'" class="sumbit_button">order now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo_overlay_filter2"></div>';
            foreach($subs as $s)
            {
                $prijs = (($s['fromprice']*($vat[$s['tax']]/100))/100);
                echo '<div style="display:inline-block; text-align:center; width:100%;">
                    <div class="pricetag">
                      <p>'.$itm['name'].' ('.$s['opt'].') '.number_format($prijs,2,',','.').' &euro;</p>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:inline-block;">

                        <div class="button_holder_ordernow" style=" padding-bottom:20px;">
                            <a title="Order Now" href="/winkelwagen.html?add='.$s['id'].'" class="sumbit_button">order now</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="photo_overlay_filter2"></div>';
            }
            echo '<br /><br /><br /><br />';
        }

    }

}


?>
```

Comment: You mean a select form for each product with different sizes ?

Comment: yes there is 3 products each of them uses this module so from so this module pretty much has to get a select of different sizes of one of them

Comment: I think youre using your quotes the wrong way round, you need double quotes `"<div></div>"` to display any html data using php?

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius it doesn't actually matter as long as it's consistent, but you can have fun if you try to build inline javascript which then needs things in quotes escaping or whatever.

Comment: @marijn it's not very clear what you want. Where should this select go? Have you got a button at present? Where is it? What should the contents be?

Comment: @ADyson The button is present atm its a div called button_holder, in that div is an a with the class sumbit_button. for every option this script is echoing one of these buttons. Instead of like 6 different buttons i would like to get a select which let the user chose the right size and when they press the button the $s['id'] needs to be the id of the selected option.

Comment: presumably you will only want 1 submit button, instead of 1 per size? And what should be the description on each line of the select? `$s["opt"]`? What about `$s['fromprice']` and `$s['tax']`? Do they still need to be displayed in there?

Comment: each line should be <p>'.$itm['name'].' ('.$s['opt'].') '</p>, the itm name speaks for itself, the opt is the name of the option so it will say "item name size M" for example fromprice and tax won't be displayed on this page.